# UI Design on Android: Is it usual to use drop down menus for commands?

Tags: android, user-interface

On a screen I am designing there is a large number of commands the user can execute. But they are groupable so I thought about using drop down menus.

I'm wondering if it's usual to use drop down menus for commands. I actually never saw them being used for anything but switching views and picking information.

And if yes, which pattern or building block can I use to implement it? Or do I have to write it by my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this depends on what you mean by "commands". In general I would say no. A `Button` may be better depending on exactly what you mean. However, it sounds like you are talking about a lot of commands in which case a lot of `Button`s may not make sense.

A [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) may be better for this especially if you are talking about editing an item and such. These are easy to set up and there is a good example in the docs that I posted a link to. A user simply long-clicks an item and a small menu with options is brought up.

An [ActinBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) may suit you also. But it really depends on your what, how you want it to look, and what your users would expect. But the first thing I think of when I read "commands" would be a `ContextMenu`

Two other options you have could be [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) and [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). Note that `PopupMenu` requires `API >= 11`. But with your comment I definitely think a `Spinner` would be appropriate.

Comment: I'm developing a game. The drop down menu shall group actions like "build house", "build skyscraper", "build bacon factory" and so on. It also has to contain at least one detail in each row (e.g. the price). And the number of commands should not be limited.

Comment: Ok, I think using a `Spinner` with appropriate titles above them would be fine for this then. The context of how it is applied matters. Here I would say that is something that a reasonable user would expect so you could stick with that

Comment: Ok, I will see if it meets the requirements and if not, I can still write a new class.

But would you finally say that it's usual and / or a good practice?

(BTW: The "reasonable user" - something we never can go by ;-) )

Comment: I don't know about "usual" I can't speak for others but I know I'm not the only one. As far as good practice, I don't see anything wrong with it if it works. I have seen some people say "Work with the ActionBar not against it". Well, if it doesn't give you what you want then I don't see anything wrong with it. It will give your app a consistent look and feel. So, IMHO, I don't see anything wrong with it

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. Was worried I might make it more confusing...Ha!

Answer (score 0):

Check out lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D:  It really pretty and easy to use.
Tutorial in the README:

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

If you more interested in something as seen on older HTC devices:

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction